# C# : Math functions

Tags: c#, double

i'm having a `List<Double>`

```
  List<Double>lst=new List<Double>{ 1.0,2.409,3.0}
```

I need to convert this list into a `List<String>`

So the result should contain

```
    { "1","2.409","3"}
```

in the result if the value does not have any floating points then need not add `.0`

Please help  me to do this

Answer (score 4):

If you're using .Net 3.5 you can use Linq:

```
lst.Select(n => String.Format("{0:0.###}", n));
```

Otherwise, you can do this the long way:

```
var output = new List<string>();

foreach (int number in lst)
{
    output.Add(String.Format("{0:0.###}", number));
}
```

Comment: This works well for the OP's example, but not "in general", see my answer.

Comment: @arul: I realise that the string format I've chosen is the right one for the OP's question, but not in general, but then I'm answering the OP's question :)

Comment: Answering for the sake of answering, not correctness ... d'oh.

Comment: @arul: I think you might be wrong. The format method just specifies how many decimals etc. that should be used, but I think it will use the underlying culture. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: 'culture specific fraction separator' relates to a different (deleted?) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take on this that doesn't rely on culture specific fraction separator, nor fixed amount of decimal places:

```
var result = lst.Select(
  n => { 
     double truncated = Math.Truncate(n);

     if(truncated == n) {
       return truncated.ToString("0");
     } else {
       return n.ToString();
     }
  }
);
```

Comment: This is not deleted:). I really can't understand why you're doing it this way, `String.Format` should take care of the culture specific parts for you. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Yes :) There was another answer calling `n => n.ToString().TrimEnd('.','0')`.

Comment: @arul: that solution is totally wrong:). But I don't think you suggestion is the solution to that, you should take advantage of the `String.Format` method. Note that I don't say that your solution is wrong, only to complicated:)

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: It's actually *not* complicated. Format of `{0:0.###}` turns `0.0001` into `0`, which is incorrect and prone to more such errors.

Comment: @arul: that part I didn't think of. But you can just use more brackets, right? Using the format method makes it easier to read if you ask me, i agree that your solution is not that complicated.

Comment: @Tomas Jansson: Sure we can, but where do we draw the dividing line? `{0:0.########}`, or `{0:0.######################}`? How about adding an extension method `static double ToFormattedString(this double)`? Never exchange cute little one-liner for correctness.

Comment: @arul: that depends on the requirement. A extension method is a good idea, but I would make it two where one take a maximum number of decimals parameter:). But all good points you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Double> lst=new List<Double>() { 1.0,2.409,3.0};
        List<string> output = lst.Select(val => val.ToString("0.######")).ToList();
```

should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
List lst = new List { 1.0, 2.409, 3.0 };
List newlist =  lst.Select(val => val.ToString()).ToList();
```

Less writing....